# Is this sentence totally correct?

Tags: articles, nouns, gerunds, noun-phrases

> The huge 747 plunged through dense **cloud cover** on approach to Hamburg
>   airport.

As far as we were taught, it should be:

> The huge 747 plunged though dense **cloud cover*ing*** on ***the***
>   approach to Hamburg airport.

Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

Both of these sentences are correct.

> The huge 747 plunged through dense **cloud cover** on approach to Hamburg
>   airport.

The "cloud cover" is used as a noun in this sentence. The use of such sentences is quite common among personals of *Air Traffic Control* Department.

> The huge 747 plunged though dense **cloud covering** on the approach to
>   Hamburg airport.

The "cover" is used as a verb and cloud is the subject of this verb.

**Edit:**

Colin Fine pointed out that your question was about the use of "the" in the sentence. "The" is an article that is used when talking about something specific. Using "the" in the first sentence would make the sentence more appropriate as the sentence is about a specific approach of a Boing 747. But as I wrote earlier, these sentences are common among the personals of ATC and they tend to keep their conversations short and specific, usually leaving out articles, as their primary concern is a safe landing and not the use of grammar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think gnoulv's question was mainly about "the".

Comment: @ColinFine : I've edited the answer to add the details about the use of "the". Feel free to review the answer and correct me if I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Phrases like "on approach, upon departure, on arrival, at liftoff, in flight" do not use the definite article because they refer to a stage in a generic process. The definite article *can* be used, but would typically be used only if there was something unusual or particular, let's say the approach had to be diverted from its normal course.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this, because it's correct: "on approach" is kind of an idiomatic phrase in the context of airplanes.  [Here are many examples.](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=%22is+on+approach%22+airplane)